# SQL Select Count using ordering

Tags: sql, informix

I had a few lines of Informix-4GL code which do the following

```
##
# prepare sql
##

let lv_sql = " select table.idno from table ",
             " where table.status != 'X' ",
             " and table.idno <= 10 ",
             " order by table.idno "
prepare table_sel from lv_sql
declare table_cur cursor for table_sel

##
# loop through results and count them
##

let count = 0

foreach table_cur into ti_num
   let count = count + 1
end foreach

display count
```

So I am getting the total of the rows in the specific table that are less than 10 in the correct order sequence but I need a foreach loop to tally the total

I have a second way of doing it which I prefer

```
##
# prepare sql
##

let lv_sql = " select count(table.idno) from table ",
             " where table.idno in ( ",
             "    select table.idno from table "
             "    where table.status != 'X' ",
             "    and table.idno <= 10 ",
             " ) "
prepare table_sel from lv_sql

##
# just get result
##

execute table_sel into count

display count
```

The problem is that the second solution crashes if I include the order by clause in the where in filter and I need it because it is not always in the correct order. Is there a way to include an order by in situation like this?

Comment: How is the count affected by the order?  That is, if you omit the ORDER BY clause, what difference does it make to the count?  You should review very carefully what you're doing because the ordering makes no sense, despite the [comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39343776/sql-select-count-using-ordering#comment66019301_39343884) about it mattering.  At the very least, you've got some serious explaining to do about the circumstances under which the order matters to the counting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I keep re-reading the question and think the answer is ...

```
let lv_sql = " select table.idno, count(*) ",
             " from table ",
             " where table.status != 'X' ",
             " and table.idno <= 10 ",
             " order by table.idno "
prepare table_sel from lv_sql
declare table_cur cursor for table_sel

foreach table_cur into l_idno, l_count
    ...
end foreach
```

... or else as other commenters have said, why does the order matter?

Comment: I'm going to accept this as the correct answer because it seems the most reliable way to do it is using a foreach loop

Answer (score 0):

Why not count directly in the first portion of code ?

```
let lv_sql = " select count(table.idno) from table ",
         " where table.status != 'X' ",
         " and table.idno <= 10 ",
         " order by table.idno "
```

Does it work ?

Comment: No, you cannot use order by idno because the idno does not appear in the results

Comment: As I understand it, why do you need the order by anyway ? You're piling the result to get the count, so the order isn't relevant at all, no ?

Comment: yea but the if the query returns the results as 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 11, 10 the result will be wrong

Comment: How can the query return a "idno" > 10 ? You are filtering out values greater than 10...

Comment: @Trent you said "No, you cannot use order by idno because the idno does not appear in the results".  Doesn't Informix all that now?

Comment: I meant to say Doesn't Informix allow that now

Comment: It might be in newer versions but not the one we're currently using

Answer (score 0):

I believe your problem lies in the way you are doing the counting. If I'm not mistaken, your Select Count will retrieve one value only, I mean this one:

```
let lv_sql = " select count(table.idno) from table ",
             " where table.idno in ( ",
             "    select table.idno from table "
             "    where table.status != 'X' ",
             "    and table.idno <= 10 ",
             " ) "
```

thus, there is no need to order. If you need the reference of the table id, and the counting of each Id, you need to add that field to your first select and also add a group by clause at the end, prior to the order by you need, something like this:

```
let lv_sql = " select table.idno, count(table.idno) as counting from table ",
             " where table.idno in ( ",
             "    select table.idno from table "
             "    where table.status != 'X' ",
             "    and table.idno <= 10 ",
             " ) group by table.idno order by counting"
```

Please let me know if this is what you were looking for

Comment: It is intended to retrieve one value only. It needs to count the total rows that are less than 10 the only problem is that they are not in order in the database

Comment: Could you add an example of what your input data is and what result you want to get?